# reading JSON stored in txt file with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i wand to save some config values to a text file so i can use them later on in my code, so i decided on saving it into a text file in a JSON format but when i try and read the value from the file i get an error

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

the text file content is:

> "{'EditDate': 1497014759002}"

```
import json
import os
cPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
configPath = cPath+'/tt.txt'
ConfigStr = {"EditDate" : 1497014759002}
print(ConfigStr)
print("-----------")
with open(configPath, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(repr(ConfigStr), outfile)
with open(configPath) as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    jstr = d
    print(jstr)
    print("-----------")
    a = json.loads(jstr)
    lastedit = a['EditDate']
    print(lastedit)
```

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. You should've `dump`ed `str(ConfigStr)` instead. Also, notice that `ConfigStr` is a _dictionary_, not a string, so the name is misleading.

Comment: Why are you attempting to `just.dump()` a Python representation of `ConfigStr`, just pass the `dict` to `json.dump()` as it is.

Comment: `json.dump(config, open(configPath, 'w'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `json.dump` to dump into the file. Pass it the object to write and a file-like object.

```
...


with open(configPath, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(ConfigStr, outfile)
with open(configPath) as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

print(d)
print("-----------")

lastedit = d['EditDate']
print(lastedit)
```

#### Reference:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump

Comment: thanks for the quick reply worked a treat, i'm very new to python to its a bit of a learning curve